# getStaticPaths and getStaticProps with domain flavouring

Tags: next.js

I have a question related to the static generation of Next.js:

I'm creating whitelabel websites for my customers; it means that I'm reading the domain where the request is coming from to load a config file and some specific CSS files. That's working fine and looks like this:

```
export const readConfig = async ({req}) => {
  const configs = await import('../configs.json')
  const domain = req ? req.headers['host'].split(':')[0] : window.location.hostname
  const config = configs[domain]
  return {domain, config}
}

Page.getInitialProps = readConfig
```

However, I'm using `getInitialProps` for that and my understanding is that because I rely on `req`, this code will be loaded for every page.

Now, let's say that I want to have a static generation of some pages, how should I proceed? Can I avoid having `count_different_domains * count_different_items` combinations? Is that somehow possible to cache the result of some queries and revalidate it later (but not as entire Page)?